Is there any method or mode provided by Tendermint-core to remove the heavily used write-ahead log mechanism?
The Tendermint-core uses a write-ahead log (WAL) mechanism to guarantee consensus safety after crashed validators recover. But this mechanism requires validators to write any received or generated messages to be written to the WAL, whose content will be synced to the disk. This process seems to incur heavy disk IO in my computer. I wonder whether the developers of Tendermint have provided any method or mode to remove the heavily used write-ahead log mechanism.
I have searched through all the issues in the Tendermint GitHub repository. It seems the developers do not plan to remove the current implementation of the WAL or provide a WAL-light alternative.
Refs:
https://github.com/tendermint/tendermint/issues/8734
https://github.com/tendermint/tendermint/issues/1589
Maybe there are other blockchains which using tendermint but ajusting the wal mechanism?

Tendermint Core is frozen. CometBFT is a successor to TC, and the Comet team is working on some WAL optimizations, eg https://github.com/cometbft/cometbft/issues/1233

Would encourage posting future questions in https://github.com/cometbft/cometbft, either a discussion or open an issue.
